# Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand is specified.

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How do I configure my ASP.NET web application in VB such that I won't get this error anymore?

I'm trying to edit an entry and then click "update" to update the entry on my website but then this error shows up. I get a similar error when I click on "delete".

I have the following configured datasourced datatable on my web application:

```
<h2>
    Sales
</h2>
<p>    
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">Hello</asp:TextBox>
</p>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 

EmptyDataText="There are currently no sales reported in this location's database." 
AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
GridLines="None">

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Salesperson" HeaderText="Salesperson" 
                SortExpression="Salesperson" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VIN" HeaderText="VIN" SortExpression="VIN" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sale_Price" HeaderText="Sale_Price" 
                SortExpression="Sale_Price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MSRP" HeaderText="MSRP" SortExpression="MSRP" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Commission_Rate" HeaderText="Commission_Rate" 
                SortExpression="Commission_Rate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Commission_Earned" HeaderText="Commission_Earned" 
                SortExpression="Commission_Earned" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 

SelectCommand="SELECT [Salesperson], [VIN], [Sale Price] AS Sale_Price, [MSRP], [Commission Rate] AS Commission_Rate, [Commission Earned] AS Commission_Earned FROM [Sales]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SqlDataSource object has no way of knowing the precise way to update the table(s) of your application unless you specify an  section within the properties of the SqlDataSource. A very rough example of an UpdateCOmmand property on your data source might be

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id=SqlDataSource1
    ...other stuff omitted..
    UpdateCOmmand='UPDATE MyAppTable Set Field=@Value, OtherField=@OtherValue Where ID=@MyId'
    ...
 >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Again, however, the specifics of the command are what you need to provide. ASP.NET can **fire** the command, but you've got to provide the guts, nuts and bolts to make it work.

Comment: This is GOOD. The only part I'm stuck on now is when I have the following query:

UpdateCommand="Update Sales SET Salesperson=@Salesperson, VIN=@VIN, [Sale Price]=@Sale_Price, MSRP=@MSRP, [Commission Rate]=@Commission_Rate, [Commission Earned]=@Commission_Earned"

Comment: It changes EVERY entry to the new information given. How do I make it so only the entry that I selected to edit will be edited and the others left alone? What would I put for my WHERE clause?

Comment: There should be a unique key value in the record being updated that you can then provide back to the UpdateCommand as a parameter. Add the "Where" clause to the end of the UpdateCommand in a manner similar to the example I posted, and that should restrict the update to just the record  you need.

Comment: In your original table, there should be a value likely referred to as an "ID" or SalesID (something like that) that uniquely identifies each record - that's called the "key" to the table. You need this to identify the specific, distinct record you're updating. That's the  "unique key value" I'm talking about.

Comment: What I posted in my original question is all my table consists of.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, but ok. From what I can tell, if this is essentially a table of car sales information, looks like the closest we can infer for a key is *maybe* the VIN, so you could that value, I suppose.

Comment: How do I value it from it's original place in the table? How would I call it?

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple for this format, and I obviously can't test this locally, but I *think* if you added an attribute to the GridView called "DataKeyNames" and assigned to it the value "VIN", and then just modified your UpdateCommand to include a "WHERE VIN=@VIN" the framework will wire up the rest for you.